# Bridge server receive POST request does not include `request.user` when using client authentication

Tags: bridge-server

I am testing an anchor setup. In my setup, the client has to be authenticated using [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) to send a request or payment.

The POST request in the receive call back excludes the JWT. The user is always anonymous even when client includes a JWT.

Bridge server posts all the data to the receive call, except for the user who sent the request. How to include the user in the request?